# configure a different path per client deps in npm

Tags: npm, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

In an asp.net core project all the client files must to be copied under the **approot** directory to be deployed correctly: **jspm** let you define a proper directory for client deps, but with npm I have to copy the files from **node_modules**
directory to the **approot\node_modules** using a gulp task.
Since I'm not interested in filtering or manipulating the files before the deploy, but I just what that the files in the installed module are deployed, there is some way to do this without use gulp ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `npm` to do that. Add a script to your package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
      "copy": "xcopy from to"
  }
```

Then you can call `npm run-script copy` to have it executed. I used `xcopy` as an example, you can use whatever you like. There is some more documentation about [scripts in npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts).

Comment: the problem is to select automatically client packages from dev packages. I found **gulp-npm-files** that does what I want. I'm looking just for the same result without using gulp.

Comment: There is `npm ls -prod -parseable` that could be used to get the list of the modules you want, but you would have to do some scripting with the output I suppose.